# Merge multiple records into 1

Tags: sql, oracle

I have a table which looks like this:
[image: Source Table]

I'm trying to write a query which will return this:
[image: Desired result]

I'm trying to merge records based on the effect_date, but only if the end_dates are within the effect_date and end_date range.

Comment: How can the effect_date value *not* be within a range that contains itself as one of the boundaries?

Comment: The end_date of 1/21/2012 is not between effect_date 1/22/2012 and end_date 2/4/2012.

Answer (score 1):

```
select employee
,      effect_date
,      max(end_date) end_date
,      max(clinical_fte)
,      max(admin_fte)
,      max(mgmt_fte)
,      max(other_fte)
from   table
group by employee
,      effect_date
```

As stated before by Chris Farmer, the second requirement that end date has to be between effect_date and end_date is silly, because it will always be true.
I've chosen max for all records you want to merge, because you haven't stated how you want to merge them. Feel free to adjust to your needs ;)

Comment: He said merge, I would have assumed `sum(...)` on the numerics would be more appropriate?

Comment: Using max(end_date) solves part of the problem.  That merges the first 2 records together.  I now need to merge the 2nd and 3rd records together.  It looks like I explained the issue poorly.

Answer (score 0):

Try this SQL Query:

```
select *
from TABLE
where end_date between effect_date and end_date
```

Comment: If you'll notice, I'm merging the first 2 records into 1, using the effect_date and the greatest end_date.  I then need to merge the last 2 records into 1, retaining the effect_date and again getting the greatest end_date, which in this case is the same.